# Generate new column based on another column sequencing - SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

Hi I am trying to do in Teradata V14 sql .
My source table is like this :

```
acc  col1  col2

100  12     13
100  13     14
100  17     23
100  22     109
100  23     110
100  29     130
```

My target table should be :

```
New_Col1 New_Col2 Acc col1 col2

1          1      100  12     13
2          1      100  13     14
3          2      100  17     23
4          3      100  22     109
5          3      100  23     110
6          4      100  29     130
```

New_Col1 - Row number
New_Col2 - If col1 and col2 are in sequence same value should be for New_COl2. Else new sequence number should be generated
Can any  help me in achieving this.

Comment: And your logic behind these new columns is....?

Comment: Added Siyual. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need nested OLAP-functions:

```
SELECT dt.*,
   sum(flag) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY acc
         ORDER BY new_col1
         ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM
 (
   SELECT t.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY acc ORDER BY col1, col2) AS new_col1,
      CASE WHEN col1 = MIN(col1) -- col1 is sequential
                       OVER (PARTITION BY acc
                             ORDER BY col1,col2
                             ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) + 1
            AND col2 = MIN(col2) -- col2 is sequential
                       OVER (PARTITION BY acc
                             ORDER BY col1,col2
                             ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) + 1
           THEN 0 -- will be assigned to the previous group
           ELSE 1 -- will be assigned to a new group
      END AS flag   
   FROM tab AS t
 ) AS dt
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the second new column is just whether *col1* is in sequence.  You can do this with `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (partition by acc order by col1),
       dense_rank() over (partition by acc order by grp),
       acc, col1, col2
from (select t.*,
             (col1 - row_number() over (partition by acc order by col1)) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```